# C# Windiws IoT core - Display and Scroll text in Textblock over an Image Grid

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, iot

Working on IoT Project using Windows IoT core. So Far Images, Videos and Audios are able to display on the Display. Need to add a scrolling Text at the bottom

## The Code Developed so far XAML is:

```
<Page
x:Class="Digital_Notiec_Board_V1._2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Digital_Notiec_Board_V1._2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="#FF222222" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">



    <Image x:Name="imageInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <MediaElement x:Name="audioInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <MediaElement x:Name="videoInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="ScrollText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="63" Margin="0,1017,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1910" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"/>


    <!--
    <WebView x:Name="webViewInstance" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    -->
</Grid>
```

Please help me out with suggestion. If possible any Base to check On.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer) to represent the text area.Please refer to following XAML codes.To make your app responsive and adaptive,it is a good choice to use XAML properties and layout panels.Please reference [Define page layouts with XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layouts-with-xaml).

```
<Page
x:Class="Digital_Notiec_Board.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Digital_Notiec_Board"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="#FF222222" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="200"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="200"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition MaxHeight="200"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="imageInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="audioInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <MediaElement x:Name="videoInstance" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ScrollText" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" Text="TextBlock" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto">

        </TextBlock>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```